# Calculation of distance between origin and a point based on elevation and azimuth angle in 3 d Cartesian system

Tags: trigonometry, mathematical-physics, 3d, coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates

I am working on a computer vision project which involves a camera that gives me azimuth and elevation of an object in 3d space with the camera being on the origin of the co-ordinate system

Is there any way using mathematical calculations that I can obtain the distance between origin and the detected object by using the azimuth and elevation angles provided by the camera system.

Thanks.